# How two unidirectional mapping is different from bidirection mapping in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am reading the book "Hibernate in Action" and finding difficulty to grasp the following concepts.

[image]

I am unable to understand why there are two different in-memory representation of same foreign key and why would hibernate detect two different changes to the foreign key when the following code is executed:

```
bid.setItem(item)
bids.add(bid)
```

The bid stored in the Item's bids collection and bid both refer to the same foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

`Item` keeps a collection of `Bids` in memory and `Bid` keeps the `Item` in memory.

```java
Item
------
Collection<Bid> bids;
```

```java
Bid
------
Item item;
```

```java
Bid bid = new Bid(...);   //bid object
Item item = getItemFromDb();  //item object

bid.setItem(item);
bids = item.getBids();
bids.add(bid);
```

In case you set an `item` for a `bid`, you also have to make sure to update the `bids` collection of the `item` object to keep everything in sync. Otherwise the `bid` object would have the `item` associated with it, however the `item` object would not have that `bid` in its collection, which means the `item` object would be out of sync.

Hope this helps!